# Whats the proper way to create a cor in solr 4.10.4

Tags: solr

Solr 4.10.4 wont allow me to create a core.
When I try creating a core I get the following error

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'blog': Unable to create core [blog] Caused by: 
Can't    find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or  
'/Users/ra/desktop/solrx/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/blog/conf
```

I'm using the admin to do this. I also tried

```
bin/solr create -c blog
```

and it still doesnt work how do you create a core in solr 4.10.4

Comment: To create a core using the admin you must have the core directory with the config files first. In other words the admin just provide a way to register the core to Solr (creating the core.properties file). Can you provide the error when you tried to create the core using console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. the tutorial I am reading says to place blog in

```
example/
```

when it's supposed to be in

```
example/solr/
```

tht made it work hope it helps someone